# Is different sample size okey for a Repeated measure-between Subject experiment?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, missing-data

I have data from a between-subject experiment (Repeated measures, two conditions). Condition A has 15 participants while condition B is with 19. The difference is due to missing data.

My aim is to use this data to compare the frequentist( **lme4**) approach to the Bayesian approach (**brms**).

What can I do about the difference in sample size between A & B?

Comment: It might be informative to remove the missing data from both groups and regress them together as a single data set. There is a possibility that something interesting could be found from this, and such a test is certainly easy to perform..

Comment: @JamesPhillips Why & how to combine two different datasets(two conditions) into a single data set to compare the difference between the two conditions?

Comment: I was discussing this portion of your question: "The difference is due to missing data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the frequentist and Bayesian approaches are likelihood-based approaches in this case. And likelihood-based approaches give you valid results under both the missing completely at random and missing at random missing data mechanisms. This is under the proviso that the model is correctly/flexibly specified. This includes also the variance-covariance structure for the repeated measurements. That is, you should model the correlations in the repeated measurements adequately.

In both approaches you can/should work with all available data. You should not do a complete cases analysis (i.e., only consider the 15 subjects who provide all measurements) because this will be less efficient and also be valid only under missing completely at random.

Comment: For bayesian I was not skeptical about including all data. But for doing ANOVA, isn't different sample sizes a problem considering the difference between the conditions w.r.t the data is around 20%.

Comment: Package **lme4** does not do ANOVA. It fits mixed-effects models using maximum likelihood or restricted maximum likelihood (the latter being only applicable for continuous outcomes and normal error terms).